# How I Save and Load Text in python

Tags: python

Ok this probably sounds stupid, but I am looking for a way to save text with starters that the loading part can look for to load the info and put it into variables to then be displayed

I am using

```
with open("save.txt", "w") as file:
  file.write("'" + text) # save.txt is the file I am using to save the text
# ' to start a line and 'text' to set the text
```

And I Open it with

```
with open("save.text", "r") as file:
  for line in file:
    print(line.split("'")[1])
```

How do I make it that I can save it in like a variable  from so I can call it when I need it

If you want to know what I am using it for:

https://fasta-project.ravinclaw.repl.co/

created on replit.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the point of injecting quotation marks into your file on-disk? If you want to have multiple items and separate them, it's better to use lines (if the items can't contain lines), or literal NULs (if they can be any valid C string) or a structured format like JSON or Pickle otherwise.

Comment: As for how to call your code when you need it -- use a function for that. One _could_ use a property to make it look more variable-like, but that's a bad idea: it means people using your code (potentially including a future version of yourself) don't know from looking at it that something expensive is being done on access, so they're more likely to reload the data over and over when it could just be loaded once and reused.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why not use list to store lines and print lines when you want?

```
txt_variable = []
text = 'Some text from anywhere ...\nSome text from anywhere ...'
txt_variable.append(text)

for line in txt_variable:
    print(line)
```

Similarly, you can use a string:

```
txt_variable = ''
text = 'Some text from anywhere ...\nSome text from anywhere ...'
txt_variable += text

for line in txt_variable.split('\n'):
    print(line)
```